# Can't --resync nodeos - How do I cleanly shut down?

Tags: testnet, single-node

I made a typo when I was creating and launching a single node test net.

I am trying to 'start again' but I don't know if I'm going about it the right way.

Here is what happens when I type `nodeos --resync`

```
Mikeys-iMac:nodeos mikey$ nodeos --resync
421570ms thread-0   chain_plugin.cpp:125          plugin_initialize    ] initializing chain plugin
421570ms thread-0   chain_plugin.cpp:166          plugin_initialize    ] Resync requested: wiping database and blocks
421598ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:247           plugin_initialize    ] configured http to listen on 127.0.0.1:8888
421598ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2822           plugin_initialize    ] Initialize net plugin
421598ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2843           plugin_initialize    ] host: 0.0.0.0 port: 9876 
421598ms thread-0   net_plugin.cpp:2915           plugin_initialize    ] my node_id is d51338e2e9cc58ddaf4c948c81b7c7fb195002200751be0e8cea7db4e78511f5
421599ms thread-0   main.cpp:94                   main                 ] nodeos version a7d77526
421599ms thread-0   main.cpp:95                   main                 ] eosio root is /Users/mikey/Library/Application Support
421599ms thread-0   controller.cpp:1073           startup              ] No head block in fork db, perhaps we need to replay
421599ms thread-0   controller.cpp:264            initialize_fork_db   ]  Initializing new blockchain with genesis state                  
421625ms thread-0   controller.cpp:208            init                 ] unconf_blocknum: 1 
421625ms thread-0   chain_plugin.cpp:253          plugin_startup       ] starting chain in read/write mode
421625ms thread-0   chain_plugin.cpp:258          plugin_startup       ] Blockchain started; head block is #1, genesis timestamp is 2018-03-02T12:00:00.000
421625ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:285           plugin_startup       ] start listening for http requests
421625ms thread-0   http_plugin.cpp:291           plugin_startup       ] http: Underlying Transport Error
421625ms thread-0   fork_database.cpp:94          close                ] states.size(): 1 
421626ms thread-0   controller.cpp:218            ~controller_impl     ] db.revision(): 1 head->block_num: 1 blog.read_head()->block_num(): 1 
422176ms thread-0   main.cpp:101                  main                 ] Throw location unknown (consider using BOOST_THROW_EXCEPTION)
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >
std::exception::what: bind: Address already in use
```

How do I restart EOS so that I can try the tutorial again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the nodeos process is still running judging by this output:

```
std::exception::what: bind: Address already in use
```

(your current nodeos process is trying to use the same address/port that's being used by the previous process that never exited)

Usually when this happens to me I find the process number with:

```
ps aux | grep nodeos
```

This will give an output like:

```
USERNAME+ 19218  1.3  0.2 1154228 45116 pts/0   S+   21:39   0:00 ./nodeos
```

Here the process id is 19218, you can kill it with:

```
sudo kill -9 19218
```

It looks like you're using a mac, so you can also use the activity monitor to kill the process if you can find it as well.

If that doesn't fix it, delete the data directory where the blocks are being stored (the location of this directory will change depending on which version of EOSIO and [which OS you're running](https://www.reddit.com/r/eos/comments/8dkvlz/which_directory_the_eos_generated_blocks_are/)) and try again.

If all else fails, either rm -r the build directory and run ./eosio_build.sh again, or delete the entire eos directory and pull from git again.

Answer (score 0):

The process is still running. You can kill the process by name using pkill:

`pkill -9 nodeos`

or as mentioned, you can also kill by process id:

`ps | grep nodeos`  to list the pid followed by `kill -9 <pid>`